# Normalizing a list with both positve and negative numbers to the range [-1 1]

Tags: python

For example, I have a list [-518.8134, 480.1884,160.4761]
How to normalize this to [-1 1] range?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this yourself or use a library such as scikit-learn which has a [`MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).

```
data = [-518.8134, 480.1884, 160.4761]

# manual scaling
scaled = [-1 + 2 * (x - min(data)) / (max(data) - min(data)) for x in data]
print(scaled)
# [-1.0, 1.0, 0.3599364886029235]

# using scikit-learn's MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform([[x] for x in data])
print(scaled)
# [[-1.        ]
#  [ 1.        ]
#  [ 0.35993649]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's more general hint :

To transform list $L$ to range $[0, 1]$, you can do following :

```
import numpy as np


L = (L - np.min(L))/(np.max(L) - np.min(L))
```

Why does this works? For intuition you can check that the minimum number in $L$ will give 0 and maximum will give 1. The rest will fall in between. Now you can transfer this to $[a, b]$ simply first by multiplying $(b-a)$ (which will shift everything to range $[0, b-a]$) and then adding $a$ (which will shift everything to $[a, b]$).